# How to name Excel worksheets alphabetically?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will copy actual sheet and name it with next letter of the alphabet. First sheet "A" always exists in the workbook, other sheets (B, C, D, etc.) will be added as necessary. I managed to put together the following piece of code that can create sheet "B". Issue is that when copying sheet "B", I get Run-time error '1004' indicating error on the last line of code.

```
Sub newList()
' New_List Macro
Dim PrevLetter As String

PrevLetter = "ActiveSheet.Name"
ActiveSheet.Copy after:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = Chr(Asc(PrevLetter) + 1)

End Sub
```

Can anyone of you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is giving an error as Soren mentioned.

However your code will give an error if sheet "A" is active after creation of "B" as sheet "B" already exists.

You might want to try this? for this, it's not important which sheet is active. Also this code will let you create sheets beyond `Z`. So sheets after `Z` will be named as `AA`, `AB` etc..

- Using this code, In XL2007+ you can create sheets up till `XFD` (more 16383 sheets)
- Using this code, In XL2003 you can create sheets up till `IV` (more 255 sheets)

**CODE:**

```
Sub newList()
    Dim PrevLetter As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim wsname As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A")
    ws.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
    wsname = GetNewName
    wsNew.Name = wsname
End Sub

Function GetNewName() As String
    Dim NewWs As Worksheet

    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns.Count
        ColName = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set NewWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ColName)

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            GetNewName = ColName
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I am really surprised to receive answers so quickly. All variants work, however, Siddharth's solution is most useful for me indeed, due to possibility to create new sheet from any sheet. Thank all of you, guys.@Søren,@Chris

Answer (score 1):

You should simply write your code like this instead:

```
Sub newList()
' New_List Macro
Dim PrevLetter As String

PrevLetter = ActiveSheet.Name             '<--- Change made to this line
ActiveSheet.Copy after:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = Chr(Asc(PrevLetter) + 1)

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** This is not a "best practice code" answer. This just points out what in your own code were returning the error. The other answers to this question (so far) are indeed much more sophisticated and correct ways of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you could do this:

```
Sub newList()
' New_List Macro
    Dim PrevLetter As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.ActiveSheet
    PrevLetter = ws1.Name
    ws1.Copy After:=ws1
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Chr(Asc(PrevLetter) + 1)

    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing

End Sub
```